# Python - CSV file blank after using CSV writer

Tags: python, csv

I'm very new at this and I'm having trouble writing a CSV file from a webscraping. Can anyone help? Thank you!

```
import sys
import urllib2
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#web scraping wind data
r_wind = requests.get('http://w1.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KCQX.html')
html_wind = r_wind.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_wind, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table')
rows_wind = table.findAll('tr')
rows_wind = rows_wind[1:]

#writing to a csv file
csvfile_wind = open("wind.csv","wb")
output_wind = csv.writer(csvfile_wind, delimiter=',',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for row in rows_wind:
    Date = cells[0].text.strip()
    Time = cells[1].text.strip()
    Wind = cells[2].text.strip()
    output.writerow([Date,Time,Wind])
csvfile_wind.close()
```

Comment: I think this `output.writerow([Date,Time,Wind])` should be `output_wind.writerow([Date,Time,Wind])` ?

Comment: And also... `html_wind = r_wind.text` should be `html_wind = r_wind.text()`

Comment: Hi @eah. In order for us to help you, please tell us your *expected* result, and what's the *actual* result. What error are you getting, and where? If there is no error, could you be specific about what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Hi @Rob--I'm trying to get the table on the website to save as a CSV file. My code appears to be working--I'm getting no errors, but when I go to open the file, it is completely blank. Also, I tried to read the file within the Python console and nothing happens.